# SDRPlay RSP1 and broadcast band (AM) interference

Tags: software-defined-radio, filter

I heard the SDRPlay RSP2 has an AM notch filter, but I don't want to spend that much money.  How is the RSP1 for broadcast band interference?  Will I need a preselector? I already have an MFJ-1020c but am hoping to sell it to offset some of the cost of the SDRPlay.

Comment: Welcome to Amateur Radio Stack Exchange. Be sure to take the tour at ham.stackexchange.com/Tour

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not great, especially if you're in a densely populated area, but frankly neither is the RSP2. The RSP2's most compelling feature is arguably the High Z input, which does not include the AM BCB filter.

You'll see images throughout the LF and MF frequency range if you have strong AM stations in the local area. An additional preselector (it has a set of preselectors already built in) will help a bit, but a proper AM BCB band stop filter, a grounded metal enclosure, and particular attention to preventing common mode current on the feedline will get you a long way toward entirely eliminating overload.

The High Z input significantly improved performance on HF and LF, with better sensitivity particularly below 3MHz, and a bit better SNR as well, perhaps because of changes in how the signal is routed through/around the preamp.

If you're going to use it primarily for VHF and up, the RSP1 will do just fine. If you're going to use it for 80-10m, with a bandstop filter, I think you'll find it quite usable. If you want good low band performance, the 2 is worth the extra money, to be sure.

Comment: That's great information.  Thank you.  I live within 2 miles of a 1kw AM station.  I currently have an RT2832U dongle with an 80 foot long wire attached to a grounded (to a copper pipe stuck in the ground) 9:1 balun, then running through the MFJ-1020c (also grounded - to copper plumbing), and the MFJ is the only thing keeping the broadcast interference at bay right now. But my noise floor with the dongle is about -80db, which is pretty much useless for weak signals in HF/LF, which is what I listen to exclusively.  Seems that the RSP2 is the way to go. Thanks again.

Comment: Happy to help! If that answered your question, don't forget to "accept" the answer, otherwise the bot will keep floating your question to the top of the page periodically.

Answer (score 2):

I bought the RSP2, and it suffers from AM broadcast band interference on HF bands, even with the AM/FM filter on. I have a 1Kw transmitter at 1350KHz about 4 Km from my house, and it bleeds thru on all HF, however when you select a ham band it seems better ??? Anyway, I am building a high pass filter to cut out anything below 2 MHz, there is no other option. Or you can buy one. I love the receiver, no regrets, if I lived further from the transmitter I wouldn't have any issues.

Comment: Hello Bill, and welcome to ham.stackexchange.com!  Please consider taking [the tour](https://ham.stackexchange.com/help) to get the most from this site, which is different from the ham forums.